# Inserir em tabela e depois clicar usando Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou inserindo dinamicamente em minha tabela, até aí tudo ok. O problema é quanto tento clicar em uma das linhas e não tenho resposta, creio que não estou inserindo no DOM, alguém poderia me ajudar.

INSERINDO:

```
$('#tabelaChat').append('<tr><td style="font-size: 9pt;">'+ data.flag[i].nome +'</td></tr>');
```

AO CLICAR:

```
$('#tabelaChat tr').on('click', function(e){
                alert("Teste");          
                return false;
});
```

Comment: Não está muito clara qual a relação do `append` com o `click`... Tem certeza que seu `data.flag[]` contém dados?

Comment: brasofilo, os dados estão carregando perfeitamente porque aparece na tabela. O que não aconteceu era o click, eu não estava conseguindo add no DOM, a resposta foi solucionada abaixo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta usar assim

```
$('#tabelaChat').on('click','tr', function(e){
                alert("Teste");          
                return false;
});
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado #vcrzy.

Comment: POr nada amigo, para tu fazer daquela forma, não deve usar o on. Bastava apenas $('#tabelaChat tr').click(function(){}); ok. Abrs

Comment: Então fiz o teste com essa segunda forma, mas não deu certo. Vou utilizar com o 'on' que está ok. Valeu.

Comment: ahuhauhaua ta bom. valeu